# Understanding sub queries in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Why does give the error: Incorrect syntax near ')'?

```
select * from 
(
    select * from ordersview 
)
```

I understand that you wouldn't want to do this but shouldn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an alias;

```
select * from 
(
    select * from ordersview 
) T  /* or AS T */
```

Not only is this required, but has the benefit of you being able to refer to `T.?` in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use In keyword to write inner query

```
Select * from tablename where columnName in(your Inner query)
```